# How to compare lists in tuples

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, maximum

I have one problem write a function to maximize the positive number of tuples of a given list which satisfy the condition that there exists no number (except zero) two or more times in one tuples.

For example, a list like `e1={{{0,0},{0,1}},{{0,0}},{{1,2},{3,4}}}`. All tuples which satisfy the condition are

> `{{0,0},{0,0},{1,2}}`,`{{0,0},{0,0},{3,4}}`,`{{0,1},{0,0},{3,4}}`.

The positive number of these three tuples are 2,2,3 and hence the maximum positive number in this example is 3.

Since my list is very long, I want to make my current code faster. Thank you very much.

My current code is:

```
ClearAll@findTuples;    

findTuples[e_] := findTuples[e, {}];

findTuples[e_ /; Length[e] == 1, v_] := List /@ First@e;

findTuples[e_, verboten_] := 

If[Min[Length /@ e] > 0, 
 Module[{r, v, o, s, i, m}, 
o = Ordering[e, All, Length[#1] < Length[#2] &];
i = InversePermutation@o;
s = e[[o]];
#[[i]] & /@ Flatten[Function[f, v = Cases[Flatten@f, Except[0]];
    r = Fold[DeleteCases[#1, {#2, _} | {_, #2}, {2}] &, Rest@s, v];
    Prepend[#, f] & /@ findTuples[r, Union[verboten, v]]] /@ 
   First@s, 1]], {}];

Tallnew = findTuples[e1];

mm = Max[Array[Count[Positive /@ Flatten[Tallnew[[#]]], True] &, 
Length[Tallnew]]];
```

A longer list example:

> `{{{0,0}},{{0,0}},{{0,0},{3,2}},{{0,0},{4,2}},{{0,0}},{{0,0},{6,4}},{{0,0},{7,2}},{{0,0},{8,3}},{{0,0}},{{0,0}},{{0,0}},{{0,0}},{{0,0}},{{0,0}},{{0,0},{15,3},{15,14}},{{0,0},{16,2}},{{0,0}},{{0,0},{18,2},{18,3},{18,5},{18,8},{18,14},{18,15}},{{0,0}},{{0,0},{20,4},{20,16}},{{0,0}},{{0,0},{22,1},{22,3},{22,7},{22,9},{22,14},{22,16},{22,17}},{{0,0},{23,18}},{{0,0}},{{0,0},{25,2},{25,6},{25,20},{25,22}},{{0,0}},{{0,0},{27,4},{27,7},{27,16},{27,18},{27,25}},{{0,0}},{{0,0},{29,3},{29,18}},{{0,0},{30,3},{30,18}},{{0,0},{31,7},{31,25}},{{0,0},{32,22}},{{0,0}},{{0,0},{34,22}},{{0,0}},{{0,0},{36,28}},{{0,0}},{{0,0},{38,18}},{{0,0},{39,3},{39,18}},{{0,0},{40,1},{40,2},{40,6},{40,9},{40,13},{40,14},{40,16},{40,18},{40,19},{40,21},{40,22},{40,27},{40,29},{40,34},{40,38},{40,39}},{{0,0}},{{0,0},{42,18}},{{0,0},{43,22}},{{0,0},{44,40}},{{0,0}},{{0,0},{46,4},{46,16},{46,18},{46,25},{46,40}},{{0,0},{47,22}},{{0,0},{48,40}},{{0,0},{49,22}},{{0,0}}}`

Comment: Could you add code to generate a realistic example list. Your `e1` is a great example for describing the problem but too small for testing speed.

Comment: Yes, I can. I have put a longer list in question part.

Comment: @Feyre -Actually, I try to use my current code to calculate a longer list than e1 and it spend a very long time and cannot get an answer.

Comment: In the long example every sublist begins with {0,0}, is that always the case?

Comment: Yes, every sublist in e1 begins with {0,0}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this works properly, it is faster than your code but still pretty slow.

```
purge[{a_, b_}, list_] := DeleteCases[Select[FreeQ[a | b]] /@ list, {}]

f[{first_, rest___}] := Max[{(Length[#] + f@purge[#, {rest}]) & /@ first, f[{rest}]}]
f[{}] = 0;

f[SortBy[e1 //. {} | 0 -> Nothing, Length]]
(* 20 *)
```

Comment: I got one problem is that if one tuple is `{{0,0},{0,0},{0,0}}` the result will become `f[SortBy[Nothing,Length]]`

Comment: I think this function works really well but the only problem is the tuple `{{0,0},{0,0},{0,0}}` and the information  `Nonatomic expression expected at position 1 in SortBy[Nothing,Length]` shows on screen. I tried to change the value of `Nothing`, but the result does not correct. I would be very appreciated if you can help me to solve this problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: What's the input list `e1` that gives that error?

Comment: @Simon-Because e1 is randomly selected. If `e1={{{0,0}},{{0,0}},{{0,0}}}`, then the reslut should equal to zero.

Comment: @user44565, the list only reduces to Nothing if every element is {0,0} so the simplest fix is to something like `If[Max[e1] == 0, 0, f[...]]`

Comment: Thank you very much. I have solved this problem.